# (Online?) short story inspired by those "choose a special power" CYOAs

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, magic, soft-sci-fi

It may have been on a blog, as a riff on those dime-a-dozen choose-your-own-adventure images shared on social media. There were some people (eight I think), each of whom chose a special power, I think though drinking a potion (or was it touching a stone?). I distinctly remember Red was infinitely tireless, one of them could send messages to his past/future self, relaying messages through centuries, and one died at the bottom of the ocean because the power that allowed him to breathe underwater didn't allow him to escape the immense pressure there. Red was made out to be the weakest choice at the start, but the culmination of the story is that he saves the Universe (?) by perpetually moving a generator, tireless as he was. Any help is appreciated, it's been at the tip of my mind for ages now.

Comment: Aw shucks just found it. Never mind, feel free to delete this.

Comment: You can add what you have found as an answer to help other users who may be looking for the same thing as you

Comment: Hi Sam. Yes, please add an answer saying what the story is as I'd like to read it.

Comment: [What did you see, denvercoder9? ***What did you see?!***](https://xkcd.com/979/)

Comment: duplicate of this? https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/193637/online-post-short-story-about-potions-that-give-you-different-powers